# ActionController::UnknownFormat in Controller ( #index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, format, link-to

I have a `link_to` calling my `#index`. In this method lies a `respond_to` for a `format.js` so I can initiate some Ajax. Things is, when I look at the console I get an error 500 because of a `"ActionController::UnknownFormat"`

I have tested out differents solutions from older posts, but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

controler :

```
def index
 respond_to do |format|
  format.js { render partial: 'private/messages/load_more_messages' }
 end
end
```

view :

```
<%= link_to "Load messages", private_messages_path(:conversation_id => conversation.id), remote: true %>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this ? It's supposed to be a text book case, but I've been hitting my heads against a brick wall with this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after going around testing a wide range of ideas, I came back to my original thought and it worked perfectly. I don't know what went wrong the first time but now it is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading a HTML partial try it like this:

```
def index
 render partial: 'private/messages/load_more_messages'
end
```

Although i would recommend making a specific endpoint for fetching partials that you pass a route to since this might be something you do frequently in a project.

Something like this

```
  def render_partial(partial_route)
    render partial: partial_route
  end
```

Comment: Hum, since the idea is to use Ajax request I should be keeping the "respond_to" no? I mean, what's the point of having my "link_to" as "remote:true" then
That being say, for the purpose of my post, I cuted out variables assignement that I do have before the respond_to

Comment: Very neat that second point of yours, that will definitely make my code more pleasing for the eyes. Thanks for that tips !

Comment: @Narf if you are trying to fetch the partial VIA ajax you just need to get the response from my code snippet above and append it to DOM.

Comment: Not sure to see how it's supposed to do the trick, especially knowing that my partial is a " js.erb". I did try though, but I get the same result.

Comment: @Narf I apologize, i thought you were trying to render a html.erb that had JavaScript inside of it

Comment: no worries ! Next time I will give this info from the get go